# MacOS Excel Internal Error after copying Module with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, module, office365

I need to copy one module (Dictionary from Tim Hall - https://github.com/timhall/VBA-Dictionary) from one workbook to another programatically. For this I am using this piece of code:

```
Sub CopyMacrosToExistingWorkbook(SourceWB As Workbook, strModuleName As String, TargetWB As Workbook)
    Dim SourceVBProject As VBIDE.VBProject, DestinationVBProject As VBIDE.VBProject
    Set SourceVBProject = SourceWB.VBProject
    Set DestinationVBProject = TargetWB.VBProject

    Dim SourceModule As VBIDE.CodeModule, DestinationModule As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Set SourceModule = SourceVBProject.VBComponents(strModuleName).CodeModule

    Set DestinationModule = DestinationVBProject.VBComponents.Add(SourceModule.Parent.Type)
    DestinationModule.Name = strModuleName

    With SourceModule
        DestinationModule.CodeModule.AddFromString .Lines(1, .CountOfLines)
    End With
End Sub
```

On Windows everything is going well but on **Mac (Office 365 version 16.29)**, the file, where I will import this Dictionary modul is not working. It cant be saved and it writes this Internal error to me:

[image]
[image]

The interesting thing is, that it is enough to copy this broken file to windows, open it, save it and return it back to Mac. But this is not sufficient solution to me.

**I Have found, that if I will remove from Dictionary class module this piece of code**, the "Internal Error" is not showing, but I cant use the module without this code:

```
Public Enum CompareMethod
    BinaryCompare = VBA.vbBinaryCompare
    TextCompare = VBA.vbTextCompare
    DatabaseCompare = VBA.vbDatabaseCompare
End Enum
```

So I guess, **that something its wrong with this Enum class**. What or where could be the problem? I cant find it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It is a long shot, but have you tried using Excel 16.28?

I have several macros that worked fine since 16.12, but after upgrading to 16.29 I got some errors and I couldn't understand what was wrong with the code.

I reverted to 16.28 and all good again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I cant force anyone to downgrade the office version. I don't think this can be solved. It is just bug in office on MacOS. :(